# Problems with importScripts

Tags: javascript, web, import, worker

I'm using the web worker and I need to import ml5, p5 and jQuery library.
Before using web worker I developed the code as usual and imported the lib using the html tag `<script>` and everythings was running right.

Now, using the web worker, every time I try to import one of those library something goes wrong: the console show me errors.

This's the code I use to import the lib.

```
const jquery = 'lib/jquery.min.js';
const p5 = 'lib/p5.min.js';
const p5_dom = 'lib/p5.dom.min.js';
const ml5 = 'lib/ml5.min.js';

console.log('loading lib..');

importScripts(p5, p5_dom, jquery);
```

Comment: `the console show me errors.`  - what errors? do you know if these libraries are even able to run in web workers?

Comment: for example in a web worker, there is no `window`, there is no direct DOM manipulation - do those libraries work in such an environment?

Comment: exactly! the broblem is that those libreries use window, document.

Comment: which is exactly why you can't use them in a web worker - problem solved